# Bash commands run at terminal but not in Jenkins/Bash Script

Tags: bash, symfony, jenkins

I have a Symfony project within Jenkins
when I run the command `php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --fixtures=tests/Fixtures/TestFixtures.php --env=test --no-interaction` it works fine in the terminal directly, but it's not working within Jenkins !
This is `Jenkinsfile`:

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build'){
            steps{
                sh 'php composer.phar install --no-interaction'
            }
        }
        stage('Tests'){
            steps{
                sh 'php bin/console doctrine:schema:drop --force --env=test'
                sh 'php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --env=test'
                sh 'php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --fixtures=tests/Fixtures/TestFixtures.php --env=test --no-interaction'
                sh 'php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I get this error:

```
In LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand.php line 109:

  Could not find any fixtures to load in:   

  - tests/Fixtures/TestFixtures.php
```

what am I missing here ?

Trace of the pipeline:

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] sh
+ php composer.phar install --no-interaction
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Warning: Composer should be invoked via the CLI version of PHP, not the cgi-fcgi SAPI
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Package operations: 103 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing ocramius/package-versions (1.4.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.13.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.13.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing twig/twig (v2.12.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v2.0.18): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php70 (v1.13.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-util (v1.13.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php56 (v1.13.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/symfony (v3.4.36): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-icu (v1.13.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-apcu (v1.13.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/simple-cache (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/log (1.1.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/link (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/container (1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing psr/cache (1.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing fig/link-util (1.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/lexer (1.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/annotations (v1.8.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/reflection (v1.0.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/event-manager (1.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/collections (1.6.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/cache (1.10.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/persistence (1.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/inflector (1.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/common (v2.11.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/dbal (v2.10.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/orm (v2.7.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing beberlei/doctrineextensions (v1.2.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle (1.4.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing friendsofsymfony/user-bundle (v2.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing incenteev/composer-parameter-handler (v2.1.4): Loading from cache
  - Installing isom/code-maker (dev-master a5508f4): Cloning a5508f44af from cache
  - Installing jdorn/sql-formatter (v1.2.17): Loading from cache
  - Installing paragonie/sodium_compat (v1.12.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing pusher/pusher-php-server (v3.4.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing mrad/notifications-bundle (v1.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing phenx/php-font-lib (0.5.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing sabberworm/php-css-parser (8.3.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing phenx/php-svg-lib (v0.3.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing dompdf/dompdf (v0.8.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing sbc/auto-reporting-bundle (dev-master 4cd6866): Cloning 4cd68660b5 from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.13.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.13.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/mime (v5.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/service-contracts (v2.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php73 (v1.13.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/http-client-contracts (v2.0.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/http-client (v5.0.2): Loading from cache
  - Installing sensiolabs/security-checker (v6.0.3): Loading from cache
  - Installing sensio/distribution-bundle (v5.0.25): Loading from cache
  - Installing sensio/framework-extra-bundle (v3.0.29): Loading from cache
  - Installing slimen/log-tracker (v1.3.1): Loading from cache
  - Installing behat/transliterator (v1.2.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing gedmo/doctrine-extensions (v2.4.38): Loading from cache
  - Installing stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle (v1.3.0): Loading from cache
  paragonie/random_compat suggests installing ext-libsodium (Provides a modern crypto API that can be used to generate random bytes.)
symfony/polyfill-intl-icu suggests installing ext-intl (For best performance)
doctrine/cache suggests installing alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter (Required to use legacy MongoDB driver)
doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle suggests installing symfony/security-acl (For using this bundle to cache ACLs)
paragonie/sodium_compat suggests installing ext-libsodium (PHP < 7.0: Better performance, password hashing (Argon2i), secure memory management (memzero), and better security.)
paragonie/sodium_compat suggests installing ext-sodium (PHP >= 7.0: Better performance, password hashing (Argon2i), secure memory management (memzero), and better security.)
dompdf/dompdf suggests installing ext-gmagick (Improves image processing performance)
dompdf/dompdf suggests installing ext-imagick (Improves image processing performance)
symfony/polyfill-intl-idn suggests installing ext-intl (For best performance)
symfony/service-contracts suggests installing symfony/service-implementation
sensio/framework-extra-bundle suggests installing symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (To use the PSR-7 converters)
gedmo/doctrine-extensions suggests installing doctrine/mongodb-odm (to use the extensions with the MongoDB ODM)
stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle suggests installing doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle (to use the MongoDB ODM extensions)
kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing leafo/lessphp (Assetic provides the integration with the lessphp LESS compiler)
kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing leafo/scssphp (Assetic provides the integration with the scssphp SCSS compiler)
kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing leafo/scssphp-compass (Assetic provides the integration with the SCSS compass plugin)
kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing patchwork/jsqueeze (Assetic provides the integration with the JSqueeze JavaScript compressor)
kriswallsmith/assetic suggests installing ptachoire/cssembed (Assetic provides the integration with phpcssembed to embed data uris)
symfony/assetic-bundle suggests installing kriswallsmith/spork (to be able to dump assets in parallel)
monolog/monolog suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Allow sending log messages to AWS services like DynamoDB)
monolog/monolog suggests installing doctrine/couchdb (Allow sending log messages to a CouchDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-amqp (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server (1.0+ required))
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-mongo (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing graylog2/gelf-php (Allow sending log messages to a GrayLog2 server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing mongodb/mongodb (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server via PHP Driver)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-amqplib/php-amqplib (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server using php-amqplib)
monolog/monolog suggests installing php-console/php-console (Allow sending log messages to Google Chrome)
monolog/monolog suggests installing rollbar/rollbar (Allow sending log messages to Rollbar)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ruflin/elastica (Allow sending log messages to an Elastic Search server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing sentry/sentry (Allow sending log messages to a Sentry server)
vich/uploader-bundle suggests installing doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle (For integration with Doctrine ODM)
vich/uploader-bundle suggests installing doctrine/phpcr-odm (For integration with Doctrine PHPCR)
vich/uploader-bundle suggests installing knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle (For integration with Gaufrette)
vich/uploader-bundle suggests installing liip/imagine-bundle (To generate image thumbnails)
vich/uploader-bundle suggests installing oneup/flysystem-bundle (For integration with Flysystem)
vich/uploader-bundle suggests installing willdurand/propel-eventdispatcher-bundle (For integration with Propel)
doctrine/data-fixtures suggests installing alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter (For using MongoDB ODM with PHP 7)
doctrine/data-fixtures suggests installing doctrine/mongodb-odm (For loading MongoDB ODM fixtures)
doctrine/data-fixtures suggests installing doctrine/phpcr-odm (For loading PHPCR ODM fixtures)
zendframework/zend-eventmanager suggests installing container-interop/container-interop (^1.1.0, to use the lazy listeners feature)
zendframework/zend-eventmanager suggests installing zendframework/zend-stdlib (^2.7.3 || ^3.0, to use the FilterChain feature)
zendframework/zend-code suggests installing zendframework/zend-stdlib (Zend\Stdlib component)
ocramius/proxy-manager suggests installing ocramius/generated-hydrator (To have very fast object to array to object conversion for ghost objects)
ocramius/proxy-manager suggests installing zendframework/zend-json (To have the JsonRpc adapter (Remote Object feature))
ocramius/proxy-manager suggests installing zendframework/zend-soap (To have the Soap adapter (Remote Object feature))
ocramius/proxy-manager suggests installing zendframework/zend-xmlrpc (To have the XmlRpc adapter (Remote Object feature))
sebastian/global-state suggests installing ext-uopz (*)
phpunit/php-code-coverage suggests installing ext-xdebug (^2.7.2)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing ext-soap (*)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing ext-xdebug (*)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing phpunit/php-invoker (^2.0.0)
symfony/phpunit-bridge suggests installing symfony/error-handler (For tracking deprecated interfaces usages at runtime with DebugClassLoader)
Package symfony/assetic-bundle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/webpack-encore-pack instead.
Package zendframework/zend-eventmanager is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-eventmanager instead.
Package zendframework/zend-code is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-code instead.
Package sensio/generator-bundle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/maker-bundle instead.
Generating autoload files
ocramius/package-versions:  Generating version class...
ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
> Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters
Creating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
 // Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug                       
 // true                                                                        

 [OK] Cache for the "dev" environment (debug=true) was successfully cleared.    

> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installAssets
 Trying to install assets as relative symbolic links.

 --- ------------------ ------------------ 
      Bundle             Method / Error    
 --- ------------------ ------------------ 
  ✔   TiersBundle        relative symlink  
  ✔   LogTrackerBundle   relative symlink  
  ✔   CodeMakerBundle    relative symlink  
 --- ------------------ ------------------ 

 [OK] All assets were successfully installed.                                   

> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Tests)
[Pipeline] sh
+ php bin/console doctrine:schema:drop --force --env=test
 Dropping database schema...

 [OK] Database schema dropped successfully!                                     

Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

[Pipeline] sh
+ php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --env=test
 Updating database schema...

     82 queries were executed

 [OK] Database schema updated successfully!                                     

Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

[Pipeline] sh
+ php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --fixtures=./tests/Fixtures/TestFixtures.php --env=test --no-interaction

In LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand.php line 109:

  Could not find any fixtures to load in:   

  - ./tests/Fixtures/TestFixtures.php       


doctrine:fixtures:load [--fixtures [FIXTURES]] [--append] [--em EM] [--shard SHARD] [--purge-with-truncate] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>

Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] mail
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't gave the full path of the binary..

In terminal path is taken from profile, but whenever you used in script you have to give full path of binary.

For e. g. /usr/local/bin like this

Comment: thanks for your answer, the problem is that jekins already executed the other commands ! like `php bin/console doctrine:schema:drop --force --env=test` but when it came to `php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --fixtures=tests/Fixtures/TestFixtures.php --env=test --no-interaction` the exception happened! if ti was a path binary issue no command would be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try the absolute path to the file
--fixtures=tests/Fixtures/TestFixtures.php
or if you are on a windows env on your local, please check filename Case Sensitivity

Answer (score 0):

Check service.yaml, "exclude: '../src/{......}'" section. May be the "Fixture directory" is excluded from auto wire / autoconfigure.